# Regex remove english text from mixed chinese-english sentences using Notepad++ and Excel?

Tags: html, regex, excel, notepad++, excel-2016

I work with Notepad++ and Excel.
I have data that contains text in English and Chinese.

The data structure is as follows:

```
<p> chinese text</p>
<p> english text</p>
<p> chinese text</p>
<p> english text</p>
<p> chinese text</p>
<p> english text</p>
```

**How to delete all English text and also symbols between < p> and < /p> ?**

**So just leave the Chinese text between < p> and < /p>**

So the result is like this:

```
<p> chinese text</p>
<p> chinese text</p>
<p> chinese text</p>
```

I tried to delete English text by removing ascii characters using regex, but there is an English text that was missed.

See this pic:
[image: PIC]
Please help me, thanks

Comment: Data Example: `<p>坐在马车上的叶天，通过窗户看向远处雄伟的天炎城，一时间不由苦笑。</p>
<p>Ye Tian, ​​sitting in the carriage</p>
<p>至于原因，小糯米跟纪小小根本受不了天炎城那一百多度的高温，此时已经热的快要中暑了。</p>
<p>As for the reason, Xiaomi and Ji Xiaoxiao couldn't stand has a heatstroke.</p>
<p>小金吼倒是没事，趴在叶天脚下睡的深沉。</p>
<p>Xiao Jin’s squatting is fine, and he is sleeping deep at the foot of Ye Tian.</p>
<p>“少爷，我受不了啦！”小糯米眼见马车每前行一步，温度就会上升几度，连向叶天求救。</p>
<p>""Young master, I can't stand it!"" .</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using Notepad++:

- replace `<p>[a-zA-Z"].*$` to empty string  (regex replace mode)
- replace `\n\n` to `\n`                     (extended replace mode)
- replace `<p>|</p>` to empty string         (regex replace mode)

Comment: it works on paragraphs after the <p> </p> tag has spaces. But, if the sentence with the <p> </p> tag with the next sentence has no space, then it only works on the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/TGrW27/1

This regex will basically match and remove:

- `<p>`: Match the starting tag
- `(\w|"|')`: Match any English letter or `"` or `'`
- `.+`: Any number of times
- `<\/p>`: And watch for closing tag

Comment: it works on paragraphs after the <p> </p> tag has spaces. But, if the sentence with the <p> </p> tag with the next sentence has no space, then it only works on the first sentence. check https://regex101.com/r/TGrW27/2

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above solutions only work in the first paragraph if there is a paragraph model that extends 1 line. When I try, this doesn't work for paragraphs that extend one line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always as first line Chinese and second line English?  Then you can solve this problem using below technique.
Find what: `(.*\n?)(.*\n?)`
Replace with:`$1`  → will return Chinese
`Or if`
Replace with: `$2` → will return English

https://regex101.com/r/VIPS0s/1